# $A^2X = X$ show that $AX = X$, if $A_{ij} > 0$ and $x_{i} > 0$

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

> Let $A$ and $X$ be matrices $n \times n$ and $n \times 1$, respectively, with all entries real and strictly positive. Assume that $A^2 X = X$. Show that $A X = X$.

What I thought:

(i) $A^2 X = X \Rightarrow A (A^2 X) = A (X)$ for distributive law $ A(A^2 X) = A A (Ax) = AX \Rightarrow A^2(AX) = (AX)$, i.e., $A^2 Y = Y$ for $Y=AX$.

(ii) $A^2 X = X \Rightarrow (A^2-I)X = 0$. Be $X = (x_1,x_2,\ldots,x_n)^t$. So, $x_i > 0 \quad\forall i \in \{1,2,\ldots,n\}$. So, $det(A^2 - I) = 0 \Rightarrow det(A-I) = 0$ or $det(A+I) = 0$.

But, if $det(A+I) = 0 \Rightarrow (A+I)Y = 0 \Rightarrow AY = -Y$.

So $Y\neq X$ because if $A_{ij}>0 \quad and \quad x_i > 0 \Rightarrow AX \neq -X$

So, $det(A-I) = 0 \Rightarrow$ There is a vector Z that  $(A-I)Z = 0 \Rightarrow AZ = Z$.

So, I need conclude that Z = X.

Comment: How does $\det(A+I)=0$ imply $(A+I)X=0$?

Comment: so, I can't do this? I thought about eigenvectors and eigenvalues. If $det(A+I) = 0 \Rightarrow -1$ is a eigenvector. So, $AX = -X$. Isn't correct?

Comment: This would imply $-1$ is an eigenvalue, but I see no reason to conclude that $X$ is the corresponding eigenvector. In fact, $X$ is a matrix by definition.

Comment: Looks like $A$ is $I$.

Comment: Yeah, you have the reason M10687. Can you think one solution for this? I need conclude this for january 12 (three days for conclude :] ).

Comment: but the problem doesn't talk about invertible matrix. I think that the solution walk by strictly positive entries.

Comment: You are correct.

Comment: *Hint.* Apply Perron-Frobenius theorem, which guarantees that if $A$ is (entrywise) positive, then (a) $\rho(A)$ is a ***simple*** eigenvalue of $A$, and (b) every nonnegative eigenvector of $A$ must correspond to the eigenvalue $\rho(A)$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider the characteristic polynomial $p$ of $A$.  By the Cayley-Hamilton theorem, $p(A)=0$, and thus $p(A)X=0$.  If $p(x)=\sum_{i=0}^n c_ix^i$, this
gives $\sum_{i=0}^n c_iA^iX=0$.  As $A^2X=X$, the latter sum simplifies to
$d_1AX+d_0X=0$ for some constants $d_0$ and $d_1\not=0$.  This in turn implies that
$AX=\lambda X$ for $\lambda=-d_0/d_1$.  Now $X=A^2X=\lambda^2 X$, so $\lambda=\pm 1$, and since all entries of $A$ and $X$ are positive, it
can't be that $\lambda=-1$.

Comment: Why is $d_1$ nonzero? E.g. when $A=\operatorname{diag}(1,-1)$ and $X=(1,0)^T$. Then $d_1=d_0=0$. While it may be possible to prove that $d_1\ne0$ by using the assumptions that $A$ and $X$ are positive, as it currently stands, your proof does not sound right.

Comment: @ fpguy , you can show that $d_1\not=0$ as follows. $2d_1=p(1)-p(-1)=-p(-1)$ (since $1$ is an eigenvalue of $A$). If $p(-1)=0$, then $-1$ is also an eigenvalue of $A$, that is impossible (according to Perron theorem).

Comment: I am amazed that a false proof  was rewarded with a green chevron and $5$ upvotes.

Answer (score 4):

More generally, let $A$ be a primitive matrix ($A$ is non-negative and some power of $A$ is a positive matrix) with spectral radius $r$ and $k\in\mathbb{N}$. If there is $x>0$ s.t. $A^kx=sx$, then $s=r^k$ and $Ax=rx$.

Proof. Note that $A^k$ is also primitive and then $\not=0$; thus, necessarily $s>0$ and we may assume that $s=1$. Using the Perron theorem, cf. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Perron%E2%80%93Frobenius_theorem , since $x>0$, necessarily $1=\rho(A^k)=(\rho(A))^k$ and $r=1$. Note that $x\in \ker(A^k-I)=\ker(A-I)\bigoplus_{\omega;\omega^k=1,\omega\not=1} \ker(A-\omega I)$. Yet, $A$ is aperiodic ($1$ is the sole eigenvalue of $A$ with modulus $1$); thus  $\ker(A^k-I)=\ker(A-I)$ and $Ax=x$.

Answer (score 3):

Here is the outline of an elementary proof. Let $\mathbf 1$ be all-one vector, $D$ be the diagonal matrix whose main diagonal is $x$ (so that $D\mathbf1=x$) and $B=D^{-1}AD$. Then $A^2x=x$ is equivalent to $B^2\mathbf 1=\mathbf 1$ and we want to prove that $\color{red}{B\mathbf 1=\mathbf 1}$.

Let $y=B\mathbf 1$. Hence it is a positive vector. There are two possibilities:

1. $y$ and $\mathbf1$ are linearly independent. Let $v$ be the positive multiple of $y$ such that its largest element is equal to $1$. From $B^2\mathbf1=\mathbf1$, we get $B^2y=y$ and in turn $B^2v=v$. Therefore
   $$B^2(\mathbf1-v)=\mathbf1-v.\tag{$\dagger$}$$
   Argue that $\mathbf1-v$ is a nonnegative vector with both zero entries and positive entries. Hence explain why ($\dagger$) is impossible.
2. $y$ is a scalar multiple of $\mathbf1$. Explain why this multiple must be positive; hence explain why it is equal to $1$. Now $B\mathbf1=y=\mathbf1$ and we are done.